# How to change the default gcc compiler for python

Tags: python, python-2.7, gcc, fortran, gfortran

I have installed gcc 4.9.2 in my computer (mac osx 10.10, 64 bit), while gcc version 4.2 is shown in Python environment. I don't know why this happened.

I encountered some issues when calling numpy.f2py function, I thought it may be related with the incompatible gcc compiler.

1.Python shell

```
▶ python
Python 3.5.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jul 23 2018, 23:45:11) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

2.In terminal

```
▶ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0/4.9.2/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Configured with: ../gcc-4.9-20141029/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 20141029 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

I thought this problem may be due to that the gcc compiler was installed after python. How to fix this issue, wish for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]` you get when you start the python interactive shell is the compiler that was used to compile the python interpreter, it has nothing to do with which compiler is used with f2py.